# Vite, NPM, React Component Library Invalid hook call, externals problem?

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite, rollupjs

I was able to bundle my React Component library in Rollup, but I wanted the features of Vite for development and installed in over the weekend. My problem is that now I'm getting the following error when I try to `npm link` my vite generated distribution with another react probject. [image: error]

Basically it's saying that it can't use useContext when it gets the 'Provider" which is really just a react context. It seems like it's having a problem here in the bundle when it tries to load it:

```
var Context=/*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext(null);
```

My vite config looks as such:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), dts({ insertTypesEntry: true })],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/lib/index.ts"),
      name: "MyLib",
      formats: ["umd", "es"],
      fileName: (format) => `my-lib.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [ "react", "react-dom" ]
    }
  },
});
```

Searching said that it might be a problem with my dependencies, using two versions of react or react-dom. I've tried it with every dependency configuration I can think of and it all breaks in different ways. I think maybe npm cacheing could be confusing me or something though.

Have any ideas? Vite works fine in 'dev' mode, and the components were working ok in Rollup so I feel like it's just a dumb configuration thing I don't understand

Comment: The context variable has the name WEBPACK in it I think you missed some thigns when migrating from rollup to vite.

Comment: @CasperKuethe could be, but I think that's because the library is being used in a webpack app, that's the app which is throwing the error

Comment: If you build a library and then use it, the library should be universal. I've never seen a js library that is for webpack only. So i figured the build process must be wrong and I don't think it has anything to do with using the library in a project with another build tool.

Comment: I think I understand, but the module is being use by a webpack app, the module has react as an external dependency, so I thought that's what that "webpack imported module" was, that external version of react referenced in my component library

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems and tried tons of things, here is what eventually worked for me:

1- Move `react` and `react-dom` into `peerDependancies`.

2- Add `rollupOptions` to your build in `vite.config.ts`

```
rollupOptions: {
  external: [ 'react', 'react-dom' ]
},
```

3- Add the following after `build`:

```
  resolve: {
    dedupe: ['react', 'react-dom'],
  },
```

Here is more info about what resolve does:
https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-dedupe

And here is what my final `vite.config.ts` looks like:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    eslintPlugin({
      include: ['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.ts', 'src/**/*.tsx'], // include files to lint
      exclude: ['node_modules', 'dist'], // exclude files from linting
      fix: true, // enable auto-fixing
      extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'], // file extensions to lint
      emitError: true, // emit errors instead of warnings
      failOnError: true, // throw an error when there are lint errors
      lintOnStart: true, // lint on start-up
    }),
    stylelintPlugin({
      fix: true,
      include: ['src/**/*.css'],
      exclude: ['node_modules', 'dist'],
      emitError: true,
      emitWarning: true,
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    lib: {
      entry: 'src/index.ts', // Specify the entry point for your library
      name: '***YOUR_PROJECT***', // Specify the name of your library (will be available as a global variable)
      fileName: 'index', // Specify the desired file name for the output library file
      formats: ['es', 'umd'], // Specify formats of output library
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [ 'react', 'react-dom' ]
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    dedupe: ['react', 'react-dom'],
  },
});
```